# How to fix "AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute 'rfind'"?

Tags: python, email, pyspark

I am working on a code that attaches a file from HDFS and sends an email. I have got the code working with a file from local folder (linux home directory) but when I change the location of attachment to HDFS location I get  AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute 'rfind' error. Can someone please help?

I have changed the encoding to

```
part = MIMEApplication("".join(f.collect()).encode('utf-8').strip(), Name=basename(f))
```

and also tried

```
part = MIMEApplication(u"".join(f.collect()), Name=basename(f))
```

but still got the same error

Here is my code

```
import smtplib
from os.path import basename
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate

def success_mail():
    sender = "no-reply@company.com"
    receivers = 'user@company.com'
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg.attach(MIMEText("Scoring completed. Attached is the latest report"))
    f=sc.textFile("/user/userid/folder/report_20190501.csv")
    part = MIMEApplication("".join(f.collect()).encode('utf-8', 'ignore'), Name=basename(f))
    part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % basename(f)
    msg.attach(part)
    try:
        smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.company.com')
        smtp.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg.as_string())  
        smtp.close()
        logMessage("INFO - Successfully sent email with Attachment")
    except:
        emsg =  traceback.format_exc()
        logMessage("ERROR -  Unable to send email because of :"+emsg)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-5606e23c7cf8> in <module>()
     33         emsg =  traceback.format_exc()
     34         logMessage("ERROR -  Unable to send email because of :"+emsg)
---> 35 success_mail()

<ipython-input-6-5606e23c7cf8> in success_mail()
     22     msg.attach(MIMEText("Scoring completed. Attached is the latest report"))
     23     f=sc.textFile("/user/userid/folder/report_20190501.csv")
---> 24     part = MIMEApplication("".join(f.collect()).encode('utf-8', 'ignore'), Name=basename(f))
     25     part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % basename(f)
     26     msg.attach(part)

/hadoop/ipython/userid/pyspark/lib64/python2.7/posixpath.pyc in basename(p)
    112 def basename(p):
    113     """Returns the final component of a pathname"""
--> 114     i = p.rfind('/') + 1
    115     return p[i:]
    116 

AttributeError: 'RDD' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: Apologies. Added the full error traceback now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to replace these 3 lines :

```
f=sc.textFile("/user/userid/folder/report_20190501.csv")
part = MIMEApplication("".join(f.collect()).encode('utf-8', 'ignore'), Name=basename(f))
part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % basename(f)
```

with :

```
file_path="/user/userid/folder/report_20190501.csv"
f=sc.textFile(file_path)
part = MIMEApplication("".join(f.collect()).encode('utf-8', 'ignore'), Name=basename(file_path))
part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % basename(file_path)
```

Comment: That worked. But the attachment content looks off. All of the data in the attachment is in a single row instead of multiple rows.

Comment: well, you join every row with `""`, which means `nothing`, therefore, that's normal you only have one row. Try join them with `\n` maybe ...